# Eclipse `Ctrl+1` to switch to editor from terminal

Tags: eclipse, git-bash

I'm using Eclipse EE 2023-06 RC1 on Windows 10.

1. I went to **Keys** in the **Preferences**.
2. I made a copy of the "Activate Editor" command.
3. I set "Binding" to `Ctrl+1`.
4. I set "When" to "In Terminal View".
5. I opened a Git Bash terminal (by right-clicking on a project and then **Show in Local Terminal > Git Bash**.
6. I pressed `Ctrl+1`.

I expected this to take me to the editor. But instead it entered a `1` in the terminal.

If I close the Git Bash tab and click on the "Terminal" view tab itself, then `Ctrl+1` takes me to the editor. However this misses the point.

I found a sequence of events to force the accelerator keys to be recognized in the terminal (but only temporarily).

1. Open a terminal view tab (e.g. by right-clicking on a project and then **Show in Local Terminal > Git Bash**.
2. Open *another* a terminal view tab. (At this point the 80-column wrapping bug suddenly presents itself.)
3. Close one of the terminal view tabs.

Now the accelerator key `Ctrl+1` (see above) suddenly works! I can be typing in the terminal, and when I press `Ctrl+1` it takes me to the editor instead of entering `1` in the terminal.

However when I click back on the terminal, suddenly `Ctrl+1` stops working again. I've filed [Eclipse Platform Issue #805](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.ui/issues/805).

How can I bind the `Ctrl+1` accelerator to always transfer focus to the editor, even when I'm typing in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if there are any other commands in Eclipse that are also bound to `Ctrl+1`. You can check this by going to `Preferences -> General -> Keys` and entering `Ctrl+1` in the 'Binding' input box. This should list all commands that are bound to that combination. If there are any conflicts, try changing the binding of the conflicting commands.

For testing, I would try and:

- set the 'When' context to 'In Windows' instead, which should make the command work regardless of the active view.
- test another key binding to see if the issue is specific to `Ctrl+1` or if it happens with other combinations as well.

[The key bindings in Eclipse work on a scheme basis](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommandsKeybindings/article.html#eclipse-key-bindings)

If the terminal view is using a different scheme than the one you are configuring your bindings on, it might not recognize your custom bindings.

Again, for testing, try and define and use your own scheme:

1. Define a new scheme via the extension point `org.eclipse.ui.bindings`.
2. Assign this scheme to the key bindings you defined.
3. Have a product created.
4. Define the file `plugin_customization.ini` and set the scheme for the product via a property.

The rest will be followed in your [`eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.ui` issue 805](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.ui/issues/805)
Try and downgrade to [2023-03](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2023-03/r) just to check if the issue persists.

Comment: When I enter `Ctrl+1` in the "Binding" input box, it doesn't even show the mapping I added for this. "Binding" doesn't seem to work as a filter—that's why there is a separate "conflicts" table, and that shows no conflicts. I wish someone to try this on Windows and see if they can reproduce it.

Comment: I've used Eclipse for decades but the terminal has always been clunky. Does the development team even test on Windows? I thought it was something that couldn't be helped until I saw how smooth an embedded terminal works on VS Code and realized what I had been missing all these years. I'm filing these tickets hoping the development team will pay some attention to the experience, investigate the problems, and fix them instead of assuming I'm a newbie. So far the ticket is being ignored.

Comment: @GarretWilson Strange indeed. I will follow that ticket.